# jQuery show is blocked by long-running function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$('#someid').show();
someLongRunningFunction();
```

It seems that this code shows `$('#someid')` only after `someLongRunningFunction` is finished. Is there any way to change this behavior? I use jQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the callback parameter...

```
$('#someid').show('slow' ,someLongRunningFunction);
```

or

```
$('#someid').show('fast' ,someLongRunningFunction);
```